# Call JS prototype function from constructor (ES6 module)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm rewriting some code I have as *JavaScript* script as *ES6* modules and I'm having a problem calling a prototype function.

The structure of the original script is something like this:

```
function randomThing(a) {
    this.a = a
    this.doRandomThing()
    ..
}

randomThing.prototype.doRandomThing = function () { ... }
```

However, the call with *this.* doesn't work in the module anymore.

```
export default function randomThing(a) {
    this.a = a
    this.doRandomThing() // error: this.doRandomThing is not a function
    ..
}

randomThing.prototype.doRandomThing = function () { ... }
```

How can I call the *doRandomThing()* function from the constructor?
I guess I can define it as a var inside the constructor, but is there a way to keep the version with the *.prototype* syntax?

Comment: How exactly are you calling `randomThing`…?

Comment: I'm not even calling it yet. Just created a module inside a nuxt project and it throws the error when trying to start the dev server. If I comment those calls in the constructor out it works.

Comment: How exactly are you creating the prototype method? The code you currently posted is a syntax error. Also, where/how are you constructing the object? Are you certain it happens after you created the method?

Comment: @Bergi corrected the code. Cut it out from a bigger project and made a mistake